# The following TypeErrorImpl was thrown building ValueListenableBuilder<int>

Tags: flutter, dart, getstream-io

Getting an Unexpected null value when I am using getstream on my flutter web app.

Basically, when I signup or login on to my flutter web app using firebase, it does not show up an unexpected null value.

but when I do a hot restart or deploy on my website on my server and do a refresh it shows a null error but if I do signup or login it will work perfectly.

note: - I am using getstream.io for chat purposes and I have followed this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dt_taxX98sg&ab_channel=StreamDevelopers

This is code where it shows an error

```
 body: ValueListenableBuilder<int>(      
    valueListenable: pageIndex,
    builder: (BuildContext context, int value, Widget? _) {
      return pages[value];
    },
  ),

  bottomNavigationBar: _BottomNavigationBar(
    onItemSelected: _onNavigationItemSelected,
  ),
```

[image: my error]

Comment: can you show code for pageIndex and where it is being modified.

Comment: final ValueNotifier<int> pageIndex = ValueNotifier(0);

Comment: I have also changed my code from 

body: ValueListenableBuilder<int> () to body : ValueListenableBuilder ()

Answer (score 2):

Can you share your code in a GitHub repository where I can take a closer look?

I suspect you forgot to wrap your app with the `StreamChatCore` widget. Also, you need to be logged in before accessing the `messages_page`.

https://github.com/HayesGordon/chatter/blob/main/lib/main.dart#L42-L45

Thanks.

Comment: [code](https://pastecode.io/s/z4yzy4vo) please review @Sahil

Comment: I have also used global key for this but that also doesnot workout for me